# ros init my-app command gives error

Tags: node.js, windows, realm-mobile-platform

For the command- ros init my-app
I got the error as below:

```
  Error: Cannot find module '/home/chomroeun/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/realm-object-server/node_modules/realm/compiled/node-v57_linux_x64/realm.node'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chomroeun/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/realm-object-server/node_modules/realm/lib/index.js:102:28)
        at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

Comment: It says it can't find module, have you checked for it? What have you done to fix it?

Comment: I have searched for it but I cant find any fix for it

Comment: i have followed this link https://docs.realm.io/platform/getting-started/install-realm-object-server/installing-via-docker for installing ROS in my windows 10 pc. And i got error on command ros init my-app which is used to run the server